# How to Click Sub Menu Link in Main Menu

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to Click on Sub Menu. But it is not allowing to me Click and disappearing. In Console it is showing :

> Element Not Visible exception.

Here is `HTML` Code :

```
<a href="/web/billing/storageHandlingRate">
    <img class="navIcon" src="/web/images/nav/subChargeRuleMaintenance.png"/>
    Storage Handling Rate
</a>
```

Xpath I am using :

```
xpath(".//*[@id='globalMenuNavigation']/li[2]/ul/li[7]/a")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible and clickable as below :-

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//a[contains(.,'Storage Handling Rate')]"))).click();
```

Or

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Storage Handling Rate"))).click();
```